# How can I upload files - PHP?

Tags: php, file, permissions, upload

I have problem with uploading files via PHP. I know that there were similiar topics, but I couldn't fix my issue. Whats wrong in this code? Maybe something about move_uploaded_file() function? 
Or maybe file permisssions? I can't change Read Only Attribute ("Tylko do odczytu...").

Here are file permissions:
[image: I can't uncheck Read Only. Why?]
[image: "Zapis" means Write, "Odczyt" means Read]

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$upload_errors = array(
  UPLOAD_ERR_OK => "There is no error, the file uploaded with success.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE => "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE => "The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL => "The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE => "No file was uploaded.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR => "Missing a temporary folder.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE => "Failed to write file to disk.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION => "A PHP extension stopped the file upload."
);

$temp_name = $_FILES['file_upload']['$temp_name'];
$the_file = $_FILES['file_upload']['$name'];
$directory = "uploads";
if ( move_uploaded_file( $temp_name, $directory . "/" . $the_file ) ) {
  $the_message = "File uploaded successfully";
} else {
  $the_error = $_FILES['file_upload']['error'];
  $the_message = $upload_errors[$the_error];
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <h2>
        <?php
          if( !empty($upload_errors) ) {
            echo $the_message;
          }
        ?>
      </h2>
      <input type="file" name="file_upload" value=""><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for helping me out! :)

Comment: you need to change: `$temp_name = $_FILES['file_upload']['$temp_name'];
$the_file = $_FILES['file_upload']['$name'];` to `$temp_name = $_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'];
$the_file = $_FILES['file_upload']['name'];`

Comment: A few examples in php.net https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Thank you very much, I can't believe I missed it. Don't know why I couldn't see it.

Comment: Go enable proper PHP error reporting while you are developing your scripts, then PHP has a chance to alert you to stuff like this on its own.